# Meteor app deployed to galaxy with react server-render not attaching eventHandlers to dom

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-dom, server-rendering, meteor-galaxy

I have a meteor app that follows this file structure, https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#example-app-structure and uses React's server-render. While testing locally, `meteor --port 3000`, the client has eventHandlers attached via `/start/client/index.js`'s  `ReactDOM.hydrate(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));`. However, in production after deploying to galaxy, there are no eventHandlers attached to the DOM. I tried doing `console.log` on the client files and there were no logs. Any ideas on what i can try out to fix this issue?

PS: I tried testing this via `meteor --port 3000 --production` and i managed to replicate this issue but seems like this is not a good way to "replicate" this issue.

Comment: I tested my file structure and react implementation against this, https://github.com/juliancwirko/scotty, and other than the lack of usage of redux, my code doesn't seem to have much of a difference.

Comment: I realised that it is due to twbs:bootstrap that somehow broke the client eventHandler listeners. Will do more investigations on how to fix this issue.